# How can i send emails with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm trying to use delayed_job to send emails from an input form. In my view i have replaced the line

```
Emailer.deliver_signup(@usercontact)
```

with

```
Emailer.send_later(:deliver_signup, @usercontact)
```

but when i run the job with rake jobs:work, i get: undefined method 'deliver_signup' for "CLASS:Emailer":String

What am I doing wrong? (Note that the code works without delayed_job)

Answer (score 2):

[Delayed job mailer](http://github.com/andersondias/delayed_job_mailer) might help rather than trying to implement the details yourself.